# AngularJS select2 - how create directive?

Tags: angularjs

(sorry for my english :)

I'm using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com) in my forms with AngularUI ui-select2 directive like this:

```
<input ng-model="city" type="text" ui-select2="setupCitySelect" />
```

where setupCitySelect - object with select2 options. I'm setting him up in appropriate scope

```
$scope.setupCitySelect = {
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 2

    ...etc, about 50 SLOC
}
```

All works fine. But when we have, let say, five select2 elements on page (or part of page) - CitySelect, UserSelect, ConditionSelect etc. we get a tons of code, most of them is the same. AngularUI provides *"Global Defaults"*. So we can move repeating code (in directives):

```
var dirs = angular.module('vipc.directives', ['ui']);

// defaults setting for UI
dirs.value('ui.config', {
    select2: {
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        formatInputTooShort: function(term, minLenght) {
            var rest = minLenght - term.length;
            return "minimum: "+rest;
        },
...etc.
```

But we still need some work in controllers: to set unique properties, such as ajax-url...
And it's come on several pages, several controller. Ough...
Yes, I can put this into one file, say common.js. But I think - it's not best way. Angulas say: "use directive, Luke!". But how? Too complicated docs. I read [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Three times.
Without success. I wrote some simple dirs, but this...
It should had 'isolated' scope - can be 2 CitySelect on page - in search form and modal form above. compile function? link function?

All i need is just

```
<myapp-city-select id="city"></myapp-city-select>
<myapp-user-select></myapp-city-select>
...later, same html file
<myapp-city-select id="city2"></myapp-city-select>
```

Somebody can help?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is. It sounds like you're having problems getting a JQuery plugin to function properly. Can you post a [plunk](http://plnkr.co) or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating the issue?

Comment: All works fine! =) It's just organization of code question - can't write directive. Sorry dude, must go home now :( fiddle later

Comment: You can factor it out a bit to make the select2 directive more general, and not a directive per data item (eg one for city, one for user, etc.)  To do this you can make a new attribute that can get 'city' or 'user' from the scope.  Directives are hard, this helped me the most: http://youtu.be/iB7hfvqyZpg.  I'd watch that video and try again, you'll likely learn some tricks to help solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in the controller. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PQSq18?p=preview). showing you that all directives share the same data.

So you can have a directive with common options in the controller and pass specific options into it.

Another option is have a service that defines common options and inject the service into wherever you want.